# Poor render quality with volume

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I tried to make a cloud sphere based on [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/c6qQ-dYXd4s), however, I keep running into the problem that the render has ring-like artifacts.

I want my render to be smooth, but increasing render samples or voxel amount doesn't help.
I tried stepping up my denoising game by using compositing nodes, but that also didn't help.
[image: final render]
First picture is the final render (samples = 360), the next ones are my settings.

[image: settings]

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is actually a step pattern caused by a volume step rate that is too low. If you use cycles to fix that go to render properties-> volumes and decrease your volume step rate render. If you use EEVEE go to render properties-> volumetrics and decrease your volumetric tile size.